# jQuery slide/bounce div in from right on hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

New to jQuery but trying to figure this out.

What I have is a list of boxes of content. When we hover each box, a div will slide in from the right with detailed info (designer would like a 'bounce' effect also), and hide on mouse out.

I do have access to jQueryUI already in the project.

Here is what I have so far:

HTML for each box

```
<div class="tool_master show">
    <div class="tool_hover"> Hover information here  </div>
    <div class="tool_box" > Content here    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tool_box {
    height:100px;
    width:460px;
    position:relative;
    }
.tool_hover {
    height:100px;
    width:460px;
    background:#525051;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
    display:none;
}
```

I created a jquery script to show/hide which works

```
$(".show").hover(function(){
        $(this).closest("div").find(".tool_hover").toggle();
    }, function(){
       $(this).closest("div").find(".tool_hover").toggle();
    });
```

This gets the job done but does not provide the "experience" that the designer wants.

What it needs to do is slide in from the right, quickly, and perhaps have a bounce effect. On exit, slide out to the right. I'm not all that well versed in jquery animation.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) - replace your toggle with animate, and feed in paramaters for (properties,duration,easing,callbackFunction).

In order for this to work with your code, you'll need to change / add a few things. First, remove display:none from your tool_hover - instead we'll hide it by positioning it out-side the .show box, and then set .show's overflow to hidden.

To your CSS:

```
.show {
     overflow:hidden; 
     position:relative; /* Otherwise the absolute positioned child element ignores overflow */
}
.tool_hover {
    z-index: 0; /* Take precedence over .tool_box */
    left: 500px; /* Starting position is outside .show , effectively hidden */
}
.tool_box {
    z-index: 1; /* So hover will cover this box */
}
```

Next, we want to replace your toggle function with animate. When you hover over the box, we will tell the .tool_hover class to come back in by settings its left position back to 0. Simply replace the first .toggle() with:

```
...
.animate({
    'left' : '0px'},
    'slow');
```

and the second toggle() with:

```
...
.animate({
    'left' : '0px'},
    'slow');
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgLove/cBEhf/) to demonstrate

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. 

I also found this: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/ 
and was able to incorporate a bounce effect that the designer desired. Thanks again!